# Regex expression matches without specifying comma (,) in regex

Tags: regex

I am taking help of this website to learn `regex` and I am stuck at [this particular lesson](http://regexone.com/lesson/12). Looks like regex is wrong there.
When I write `(\w+\s\d+)((\,\d+)?)` "text" and "capture" goes green but "result" appears wrong (cross marks).

But if Write `(\w+ (\d+))` it gives below result.

```
your task       text        capture         result
capture text    Jan 1987    Jan 1987, 1987    ✓
capture text    May 1969    May 1969, 1969    ✓
capture text    Aug 2011    Aug 2011, 2011    ✓
```

Now, question is `(\w+ (\d+))` doesn't show that it going to capture comma but is right answer.And, in this `(\w+\s\d+)((\,\d+)?)` expression I have specified but it is coming wrong, why?

Comment: they are providing the task to get `Jan 1987`, `1987` as seperate captures. Real input text is `Jan 1987` not, `Jan 1987, 1987`

Comment: i think this won't help the future readers..

Comment: I understand this differently. I think you have to capture the text within the "text" column. And in this particular example you have to capture the text e.g. "Jan" and the year e.g. "1987" as different groups. That why you need the brackets around both and just the year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the capture column tells you, what you should capture. For example: Jan 1987, 1987 means you should capture two groups. 1) Jan 1987 2) 1987

They use the comma as divider between the groups. So it's not part of the string you should capture, but just a divider to tell you where the next excepted capture group starts.

If you step to the next lesson http://regexone.com/lesson/13 my example will be much more clear. In the text column there isn't any comma (e.g. 1280x720) but in capture column you're asked for "1280, 720". So this props my theory.

Comment: answer is `(\w+ (\d+))` which is one group(one group nested in another group to make a one group in total). So how come this one is correct. Correct one should be `(\w+)\s(\d+)`

Comment: No, because (\w+) would match "Jan" then the space would come and then (\d+) would match "1987". So capture group 1 = "Jan" and capture group 2 = "1987". But you were asked for 1 = "Jan 1987" and 2 = "1987". So you could write (\w+ \d+) and got 1 = "Jan 1987". But now you have no 2. So add a second capture group "()" for 1987. (\w+ (\d+))

Comment: your theory doesnt work in next lesson http://regexone.com/lesson/13 where user need to specify two separate groups here answer is `(\d{4})x(\d{3,4})` none nested group.

Comment: But in 12 there is a nested group necessary because the first capture searched for matches the whole text and the second just a part. 13 is diffenrent. No nested group. But I don't see why this should proof my theory wrong.